# I am not allowed to ask questions, yet some of the questions are perfectly fine.

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306824/minimum-level-to-complete-pokedex) has -7 votes, yet there seems to be nothing wrong with it. It is merely an experiment. Why was this downvoted? It seems to be perfectly fine. As for this: [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307562/cannot-spin-pok%C3%A9stop) seems to have given all the information asked for. Also, [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307057/super-mario-bros-3-secrets) is basically just a guide and compilation of all the tricks. Finally, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307758/how-are-pokemon-distributed) says *how* they are distributed. Therefore, it is not off-topic.

## Why am I not allowed to ask anymore?

Comment: You do realize that all of the questions you linked have negative vote counts and are therefore not "perfectly fine", right?

Comment: Currently, over 50% (6 of 11) of your questions are negatively scored. That's not good. It implies that your are either not doing enough research for your questions before posting them, or that you do not fully understand what we consider [on-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) as detailed in the help center. If you ever have doubts about whether a question will be considered on-topic or not, you can always ask here on meta and we can tell you if it's a good question.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the base question, you are not allowed to ask anymore because the system has decided you cannot. It does this because your track record for questions has not been well received.

To go into a bit more detail:

- [The first question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/306824/minimum-level-to-complete-pokedex) is a thought experiment, and is totally useless. We prefer questions that present actual problems that can be solved. While that's not required, you'll get a much better reception with those types of questions.
- [Your second question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307562/cannot-spin-pok%C3%A9stop) seems to be the best of the lot. It presents a problem, which can perhaps be solved. That said, the abundance of low quality Pokemon Go questions we get probably plays a part in how it is viewed. Your best bet is to respond timely, and provide additional information as requested.
- [Your third question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307057/super-mario-bros-3-secrets) is too broad and should be closed. We don't deal in generalities like vague, "tips" or "secrets".
- [Your fourth question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/307758/how-are-pokemon-distributed) is... weird. I can see where the close voters are coming from. I'm not sure it's very answerable, although we might be able to get close. Ingress is built off of the same system, so there's additional expertise to use to answer it. That said, it falls into the same trap as the first; it doesn't seem to present any inherent value, it's more of a question based on curiosity, or sparks a discussion. Stick to the problem statement, and show how it would be useful. That'd probably help.

Comment: I think the fourth might be somewhat more answerable than you give it credit for; I do recall reading an article within the past month or two that may have largely answered it. (Now I just need to find it again. :/ )

Answer (score 4):

Downvotes often happen for multiple reasons. Your question doesn't seem very relevant or important, even to you, so there were probably some downvotes along those lines.

That particular reason doesn't bother personally, but I still probably would have downvoted the question in [its original form](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/306824/1). Let me try to explain why, so you can try to avoid these problems in the future:

**Your question starts: "Say I am annoying, and I am just a show off".** That's not really getting me in a good frame of mind. It's also contributing, strongly, to the perception of this not being a real problem or something worth answering.

**You have a list of exceptions, things that can't be done, but no explanation.** I don't really understand this list, as I don't play the game. I have no idea why you would outlaw catch bonuses. Maybe that's obvious to someone who plays the game, but either way you should provide some kind of explanation of *why* you are stipulating those exceptions.

**Your list of exceptions ends with 'etc'.** This, to me, is the main problem. We can close questions if it is "unclear what you're asking", and we *definitely* downvote unclear questions. It's hard to get much less clear than a list of exceptions with unspecified additional entries. That invites the possibility of an answerer thinking they know what you mean (even though you included no rationale to explain the exceptions you chose to explicitly include), taking the time to research and write an answer, and then having you say "oh, no, that was one of the unspoken exceptions, doesn't count". We don't really like moving targets.

Comment: RE: Point 2: The list of things in the post are ways to earn experience without directly catching Pokemon. As the question wants to know the lowest level you can complete the Pokedex by catching Pokemon only, the catch bonuses should be avoided to avoid the extra XP gain. I have edited the question in question to make it a little clearer.